# using groovy script to validate assertions in robot framework when executing soap test by using suds library

Tags: groovy, robotframework

In my soapui test I have written a groovy script to validate all the assertions.I want to do the same in robot framework .
I am executing soapui test from robot framework using suds library.
How can I use my groovy script in Robot framework to verify all the assertions in single go like we do in SOAPUI.

please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do your verification in Groovy, but its not very simple. If your verifications are all on the XML and not things like headers or status codes, you can take the XML response from SudsLibrary and pass it to a user library. I did all the tasks to make this work manually, but if you use Maven and the plugins for Groovy and Robot Framework, it would be easier to work with.

The user library must be compiled to a .class file using the compiler, groovyc. Here you can use the SoapUI helper classes you are familiar with. They need to be on the class path when compiling. From the SoapUI installation folder, I added bin\soapui-5.2.0.jar and lib\* to the class path. For Robot Framework to use your Groovy script, classes and public methods must be used per the test library API.

```
package com.example.soapui;

import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder

public class Verifications {
    public void checkResponse(String xml) {
        def holder = new XmlHolder(xml)
        holder.namespaces["ns1"] = "http://www.webserviceX.NET"
        def average = holder.getNodeValue("//ns1:Average[1]")
        assert average == "2.5"
    }
}
```

Here is a simple test that calls a public web service and invokes the Groovy script to check the response.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SudsLibrary
Library           Collections
Library           com.example.soapui.Verifications

*** Test Cases ***
Simple
    Create Soap Client    http://www.webservicex.net/Statistics.asmx?WSDL
    Set Return Xml    True    # soap calls from now one will return XML
    ${dbl array}=    Create Wsdl Object    ArrayOfDouble
    Append To List    ${dbl array.double}    2.0
    Append To List    ${dbl array.double}    3.0
    ${result}=    Call Soap Method    GetStatistics    ${dbl array}
    Check Response    ${result}    # pass the XML to the user keyword written in Groovy
```

During execution, both Groovy and SoapUI jar files need to be on the class path.

```
C:\ws\groovy>jybot groovy.robot
==============================================================================
Groovy
==============================================================================
Simple                                                                | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Groovy                                                                | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\ws\groovy\output.xml
Log:     C:\ws\groovy\log.html
Report:  C:\ws\groovy\report.html
```